# Spring Data Rest only shows links but no information

Tags: spring-boot, rest, spring-data-rest

I am using Spring data rest with spring boot, so I wrote the code to use endpoints for an entity

So this is my entity

```java
package com.angelol.ecommerce.entities;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.annotations.CreationTimestamp;
import org.hibernate.annotations.UpdateTimestamp;

import lombok.Data;

@Entity
@Table(name="f_product")
@Data
public class Product{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "sku")
    private String sku;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "funit_price")
    private BigDecimal unitPrice;

    @Column(name = "image_url")
    private String imageUrl;

    @Column(name = "active")
    private boolean active;

    @Column(name = "date_created")
    @CreationTimestamp
    private Date dateCreated;

    @Column(name = "last_update")
    @UpdateTimestamp
    private Date lastUpdate;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "category_id", nullable = false)
    private ProductCategory category;

}
```

And this is where I am using Spring data rest

```java
package com.angelol.ecommerce.dao;

import com.angelol.ecommerce.entities.Product;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RepositoryRestResource;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;

@CrossOrigin
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "product", path = "products")
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, Long>{ }
```

So when I use the exposed controller for products (http://127.0.0.1/api/products) I get the following json

```json
{
  "_embedded" : {
    "product" : [ {
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/products/3"
        },
        "product" : {
          "href" : "http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/products/3"
        },
        "category" : {
          "href" : "http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/products/3/category"
        }
      }
    } ]
  },
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/products/"
    },
    "profile" : {
      "href" : "http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/profile/products"
    }
  },
  "page" : {
    "size" : 20,
    "totalElements" : 1,
    "totalPages" : 1,
    "number" : 0
  }
}
```

But theres no information about the `products`. Even when I try to get information of the only product I have I got the following json.

```json
{
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/products/3"
    },
    "product" : {
      "href" : "http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/products/3"
    },
    "category" : {
      "href" : "http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/products/3/category"
    }
  }
}
```

So you can see, it only shows `"_links"` but there's no information. How can I fix it?

Comment: Suggestion 1: @RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "product", path = "products"), you should set `collectionResourceRel` to `products` instead of `product`. Or just remove it, because the default value is `products`. Suggestion 2: Use the H2 memory database and [add test data on application startup](https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-rest/blob/master/rest/src/main/java/payroll/LoadDatabase.java), then upload the project to Github. There must be some mis-configuration which is not includes in the code you posted above.

Comment: @yejianfengblue well I just get rid of `@RepositoryRestResource` and it magically worked xD

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem by deleting the target file. Then I restarted the application and it worked.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30555325)

Comment: what is a target file? where is it?

Comment: at your root project folder.. u can clean that with command `mvn clean`

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to solve this problem for 2 days and finally, I got the result.
Seems like our IDE does not support the Lombok annotation which is @Data so, Instead of putting @Data on top of the entity just use the getter and setter of all the attributes of that entity and you got the result.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).